# Repeating function on each row of dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I would like to apply a function so that for each loop the function would take new input parameters from rows of a data set and provide separate results for each loop.

Lets say I have a dataset like this:

```
df<-data.frame(A = 7:11, B = 1:5, C = 4:8, D = 10:14)
```

The function:

```
loop<-function(a,b,c,d){
sm <- sum(a,b,c,d)
return(sm)
}
```

I would like to automize the following process so that the function will count sums for each row separately for the whole dataset:

```
loop (df[1,1],df[1,2],df[1,3],df[1,4])
loop (df[2,1],df[3,2],df[3,3],df[3,4])
loop (df[3,1],df[3,2],df[3,3],df[3,4])
loop (df[4,1],df[4,2],df[4,3],df[4,4])
loop (df[5,1],df[5,2],df[5,3],df[5,4])
```

I try to use `apply` function, however, I cannot do that properly. Can somebody advise me a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Or another option is `Reduce("+", df)`

Comment: if you want to keep intact the original df: ``df %>% mutate(ROWSUM=rowSums(.))``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rowSums`

```
rowSums(df)
#[1] 22 26 30 34 38
```

If you still want to use your `loop` function, try this

```
mapply(loop,df[,1],df[,2],df[,3],df[,4])
#[1] 22 26 30 34 38
```